# Error to compile in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-resources

After updating Android Studio, the following compilation error appears:

```
C:\android-studio-workspace\Biomech\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml Error:(2) Attribute "progress" has already been defined Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Marcos\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Color.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="gray">#ECEFF1</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="darkGray">#212121</color>
    <color name="grey">#BDBDBD</color>
    <color name="lightGray">#DDD</color>
    <color name="blueLogo">#5bc0de</color>
    <color name="black">#000</color>
    <color name="white">#fff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</color>
    <color name="colorPrimarytext">#616161</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#1976D2</color>
    <color name="colorControlNormal">#000</color>
    <color name="colorFABPressed">#0D47A1</color>
    <color name="colorSecondText">#999</color>
    <color name="buttonGreen">#4CAF50</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Show error log. XML looks fine.

Comment: colors.xml is ok! maybe you have an attribute named progress in another xml file

Comment: Your using the attribute `progress` somewhere multiple time..

Answer (score 0):

You probably use a class or a library that use a custom attribute with the name "progress".
The workaround consist to rename this attribute.

Comment: I don't know why this is not the correct xml file that appears as error but is the workaround working for you ?

Comment: I am using many libraries, how do I find a library that is possibly giving problem but does not show what is?